# QFileDialog::getOpenFileName() does not work in slot function?

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

I created this slot:

```
public slots:
   void openNSelect();
```

then in the function :

```
QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("select file"),"/home/",tr("text file(*.txt)"));
```

it doesn't show me the dialog,if I write that line in some other function like in the QMainWindow constructor,it did show me the window. the project is created using kdevelop with mainwindow object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put some debugs to ensure the slot is actually firing.  Half the time its a typo in the signal/slot connect that fails to wire up.

If not post more code so we can get a better idea.

Comment: Hi,I try to debug it,the console says: warning: no such slot qfTools:openNSelect()

Comment: by the way is it ok to put all my slot function in another cpp? such as slot_function.cpp?the warning says cannot find slot function in qfTools.cpp which is wierd I wrote the slot function in the slot_function.cpp,and the declare are all in the qfTools.h.

Comment: Ok, so the connect isn't working.  Without seeing your code its hard to tell exactly whats going wrong.  Show us the connect() line and tell us in which objects its called.

Comment: I've solve the problem by change the connect from:
  

    connect(item_openFile,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(openNSelect()));

to:
   

 

    connect(item_openFile,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(openNSelect(void)); so why? I am confusing..

Comment: Depends on your definition of openNSelect().